# Associating noncommutative geometries to 2D conformal field theories

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, noncommutative-geometry, quantum-field-theory, string-theory

I have recently been reading a bit about noncommutative geometry and string theory and it looked to be an open question (or at least this was open two decades ago) whether there are constructions which allow one to go from a 2D superconformal field theory to a spectral triple (a data set which encodes a noncommutative geometry), and how many ways this 2D SCFT can be taken to a triple.  String theorists typically go the over way, associating CFTs to certain geometries.

This question seems to have been ''pretty much'' sorted out in a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0308143) by Roggenkamp and Wendland, since they demonstrate that there is a construction which allows one to go from 2D SCFTs (or rather, vertex operator algebras) to spectral triples.  I am not an expert on this so I was wondering if anyone could clarify to what extent they have answered this question.  I am not sure if they have, both because they actually seem to use slightly different objects called spectral pre-triples, and because they do not formally show anywhere that their triples meet the spectral triple axioms.  The terminology of this paper refers only to CFTs (same as Kontsevich and Soibelman in their [their article on mirror symmetry](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011041)), so I think the motivation of choosing SCFTs which necessitate more involved computations is mainly physics-based.

Edit: I've done a bit more digging and this is not really a new question, going back to original work of [Froehlich, Grandjean and Recknagel](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9706132).  It seems that Roggenkamp and Wendland develop techniques which apply to certain cases with relaxed assumptions, and that a general criterion to know which 2D CFTs can have spectral triples associated to them (and in how many ways) is too much to ask for (unless someone knows otherwise).